# when trying to remove element from vector answer differs if I use another variable as value than direct vector indexing

Tags: c++, vector

I am a beginner and was stuck here why the answer differs even though val=vec[0].Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

```
vector<int>vec;
vec={1,2,1,3,1,3};

int val=vec[0];
   vec.erase(remove(vec.begin(),vec.end(),val),vec.end());
         for(auto it=vec.begin();it!=vec.end();it++)
    {
        cout<<*it<<" ";
    }
//Output:2 3 3

//Now if we change val to vec[0] then output changes.

vec={1,2,1,3,1,3};
   vec.erase(remove(vec.begin(),vec.end(),vec[0]),vec.end());
         for(auto it=vec.begin();it!=vec.end();it++)
    {
        cout<<*it<<" ";
    }
//Output:2 1 3 1 3
```

Comment: You say the output in both instances is `2 3 3`. I assume one of those is supposed to be something different...?

Comment: `std::remove` takes a reference to the value, not a copy. When that reference is to the element of the vector being manipulated, its value changes from under the function.

Comment: @NathanPierson i am really sorry, Now I have edited the output of the second part of snippet.(2,1,3,1,3)

Comment: @IgorTandetnik but aren't they both pointing to same value?

Comment: @IgorTandetnik okay, got it now what u meant.Thank You..!!

Answer (score 0):

[`std::remove`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove#Notes) takes value to be removed by reference, and it performs modification(shifting) on the elements in the range. That means the element in the range passed as `vec[0]` might be modified and then doesn't give the expected final result.

> Because std::remove takes value by reference, it can have unexpected behavior if it is a reference to an element of the range [first, last).

Comment: ohh okayy got it.Thanks a lot